# Is it possible to do token classification using a model such as GPT-2?

Tags: natural-language-processing, classification, pytorch, transformer

I am trying to use [PyTorch's transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) as a part of a research project to do sentiment analysis of several types of review data (laptop and restaurant).

To do this, my team is taking a token-based approach and we are using models that can perform token analysis.

One problem we have encountered is that many of the models in [PyTorch's transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) do not support token classification, but do support sequence classification. One such model we wanted to test is GPT-2.

In order to overcome this, we proposed using sequence classifiers on single tokens which should work in theory, but possibly at reduced accuracy.

This raises the following questions:

- Is it possible to do token classification using a model such as GPT-2 using [PyTorch's transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers)?
- How do sequence classifiers perform on single token sequences?